# How to get a fixed sidebar in Bulma?

Tags: html, css, bulma

I want to have two columns, a left sidebar, and the main content.

I want the sidebar to be fixed (and for it to scroll if need be)

```
  <div class="is-widescreen">
    <div class="columns">
      <aside id="main_sidebar" class="column">
        <h1>test</h1>
      </aside>  
      <div class="column is-four-fifths">
        <div id="editorjs" class="content">
          <!-- see the demo for the effect-->
        </div>
        <button id='save'>save article</button>    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The `editorjs` would contain lots of content and so I want the sidebar content not to be affected by the scrolling on the main section.

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/kaziqivadu/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`position: sticky` along with `display: inline-block` can help you achieve that.

Also, set `max-height` to the full height of the page and `overflow-y: auto` for the scroll functionality. I've also set the `top` and `bottom` properties to `0` in order to stretch the sidebar along its y axis.

```css
.menu {
  position: sticky;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 200px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 30px;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>JS Bin</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="is-widescreen">
      <div class="columns">
        <aside class="menu">
          <p class="menu-label">
            General
          </p>
          <ul class="menu-list">
            <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a>Customers</a></li>
          </ul>
          <p class="menu-label">
            Administration
          </p>
          <ul class="menu-list">
            <li><a>Team Settings</a></li>
            <li>
              <a class="is-active">Manage Team</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a>Members</a></li>
                <li><a>Plugins</a></li>
                <li><a>Add a member</a></li>
                <li><a>Members</a></li>
                <li><a>Plugins</a></li>
                <li><a>Add a member</a></li>
                <li><a>Members</a></li>
                <li><a>Plugins</a></li>
                <li><a>Add a member</a></li>
                <li><a>Members</a></li>
                <li><a>Plugins</a></li>
                <li><a>Add a member</a></li>
                <li><a>Members</a></li>
                <li><a>Plugins</a></li>
                <li><a>Add a member</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>Invitations</a></li>
            <li><a>Cloud Storage Environment Settings</a></li>
            <li><a>Authentication</a></li>
          </ul>
          <p class="menu-label">
            Transactions
          </p>
          <ul class="menu-list">
            <li><a>Payments</a></li>
            <li><a>Transfers</a></li>
            <li><a>Balance</a></li>
          </ul>
        </aside>
        <div class="column content">
          <div id="editorjs">
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
          </div>
          <button id="save">save article</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

or check out my [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/wejomuf/edit?html,css,output).

Comment: That's not it! I just want something you literally si on the left of this page but that it would, of course, scroll independently if need be

Comment: @relidon What am I missing here?

Comment: If you are viewing this page on a desktop, you'll see the `#left-sidebar` how it's fixed? That's what I want. Is there an option to do that? Thanks

Comment: @relidon Alright, maybe you're looking for something like this: https://jsbin.com/wejomuf ?

Comment: exactly, that's what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want sidebar completely made out of **Bulma** here is my solution *without CSS modification:*

```
<div class="columns">


<div class="column is-one-fifth">

  <aside class="menu">
    <p class="menu-label">
      General
    </p>
    <ul class="menu-list">
      <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a>Customers</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="menu-label">
      Administration
    </p>
    <ul class="menu-list">
      <li><a>Team Settings</a></li>
      <li>
        <a class="is-active">Manage Your Team</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Members</a></li>
          <li><a>Plugins</a></li>
          <li><a>Add a member</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a>Invitations</a></li>
      <li><a>Cloud Storage Environment Settings</a></li>
      <li><a>Authentication</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="menu-label">
      Transactions
    </p>
    <ul class="menu-list">
      <li><a>Payments</a></li>
      <li><a>Transfers</a></li>
      <li><a>Balance</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>

</div>

<div class="column">

  <div class="block">
    This text is within a <strong>block</strong>.
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    This text is within a <strong>second block</strong>. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Aenean efficitur sit amet massa fringilla egestas. Nullam condimentum luctus turpis.
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    This text is within a <strong>third block</strong>. This block has no margin at the bottom.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that does not generate a fixed element

Comment: This does not answer the question that is about the fixed side navbar of the dashboard menu. Consider reviewing your anwer.